# set capture size for camera android

Tags: android, android-camera

I want to set the capture size for camera in android. I want the user to capture a image using that size alone irrespective of the screen size. I see this approach in Instagram application in Android 4.x versions.

I used the following code, but it shows camera error.

```
Camera camera = Camera.open();
Parameters params = camera.getParameters();
List<Camera.Size> sizes = params.getSupportedPictureSizes();
params.setPictureSize(sizes.get(1).width, sizes.get(1).height);//height-480,width-640
camera.setParameters(params);
```

Anyone please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does your RuntimeException point to the `camera.setParameters(params)` line?

Comment: BTW, note that `List<>` is zero-based. So, if you want the first (smallest) size from this list, you should use `sizes.get(0)`.

Comment: I don't get any exception, The code works, if I open the Camera, it shows Camera failed.